# R Download .csv file tied to input boxes and a "click" button

Tags: r, rvest, httr

I am attempting to download a .csv file from https://www.fantasysharks.com/apps/bert/forecasts/projections.php? that is tied directly the input settings (is not a static download link) and load it into R.  After the drop boxes are filled in, you then have to click on the download .csv button.  I found this [Using R to "click" a download file button on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100244/using-r-to-click-a-download-file-button-on-a-webpage) that details a bit how to do it using POST, but am unable to get it to work with some modifications to that code.  I have attempted this code:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

POST("https://www.fantasysharks.com/apps/bert/forecasts/projections.php",
 body = list('League'=-1, 'Position'=1, 'scoring'=16, 'Segment'=596,  'uid'=4),
 encode = "form") -> res
res
```

but coming up with the error:

```
Response [https://www.fantasysharks.com/apps/bert/forecasts/projections.php]
  Date: 2017-09-10 15:44
  Status: 406
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
  Size: 286 B
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>406 Not Acceptable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Acceptable</h1>
<p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource /apps/bert/forecasts/projections.php could not be found on t...
</body></html>
```

Comment: You should probably read "Code of Conduct" section on https://www.fantasysharks.com/terms-of-use/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to get a CSV from a URL:

```
segment <- 596
position <- 1
scoring <- 16
league <- -1
uid <- 4
csv_url <- sprintf("https://www.fantasysharks.com/apps/bert/forecasts/projections.php?csv=1&Segment=%s&Position=%s&scoring=%s&League=%s&uid=%s",segment,position,scoring,league,uid)
res <- read.csv(url(csv_url))
```

First you set the parameters into different variables that you will later use to generate the download link with `sprintf`. Then you use the `url` function to download the file from the generated URL and finally read the file with `read.csv`.