# Use R to POST request with file download as side-effect

Tags: r, post, httr

I am trying to reproduce the answer to this question: [Using R to "click" a download file button on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100244/using-r-to-click-a-download-file-button-on-a-webpage).

The below code does work and downloads the content of the page:

```
library(httr)
res <- POST("http://volcano.si.edu/database/search_eruption_results.cfm", 
            body = list(`eruption_category[]` = "Confirmed Eruption", 
                        `country[]` = "Antarctica"), 
            encode = "form")
content(res)
```

However downloading the excel file (as with clicking "Download Results to Excel" button) with following code does not work. Both the content of the response and the file are empty.
Removing `write_disk` part doesn't help.

```
library(httr)
res <- POST("http://volcano.si.edu/database/search_eruption_excel.cfm", 
            body = list(`eruption_category[]` = "Confirmed Eruption", 
                        `country[]` = "Antarctica"), 
            encode = "form",
            write_disk("eruptions.xls"))
content(res) #NULL
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Protocol should be `https`

Comment: @Aurèle, thanks - it works. Do you happen to know why does `http` work in the first case and not in the second?

Comment: It must be a server-side restriction, I can only speculate as to why